# Local Firebase with Symfony 6.2

Tags: javascript, firebase, symfony, localhost

I'm working on my end-of-study project for a Bac+2 in web development. I'd like a push notification to appear as a pop-up for all other users when an alert is posted by a user in the database. As I'm more used to php than JS, I'm working in Symfony 6. I work locally and I've set up Mercure and I thought I could use Firebase for push notifications. I did create my project on firebase and set up the JS but when I came to connect to google "localhost does not allow connection".
Can anyone help me out of this faux pas by sharing a method for making push notifications locally or getting around this problem?

If I don't do this soon, I'm going to fall behind.
Maybe I'll just go online, but at least I'll have learned something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.